# Android : Error Initilazing the Youtube player

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I implementing a YouTube player in my app using **YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi** to play videos I add into my app. It was working all fine till two days back when an error started to show up suddenly. I have been trying to solve this, but have failed. Please help me out.

**onCreate**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_lightbox);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_youtube_activity);
        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        final YouTubePlayerView playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youTubePlayerView);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            millis = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_VIDEO_TIME);
        }

        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            mVideoId = extras.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        } else {
            finish();
        }

        playerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);



    }
```

**onInitializationSuccess**

```
  @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
    youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
    youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
            isFullscreen = b;
        }
    });
    if (mVideoId != null && !b) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(mVideoId);
    }

    if (b) {
        youTubePlayer.seekToMillis(millis);
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error creating YouTubePlayerView
  com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Exception thrown by invoked constructor in com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The concrete class implementing IObjectWrapper must have exactly *one* declared private field for the wrapped object.  Preferably, this is an instance of the ObjectWrapper<T> class.
                                                                                    at tff.a(SourceFile:76)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.<init>(SourceFile:147)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Can anyone point out whats the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based from this [forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614190/youtubeplayersupportfragment-and-appcompatactivity-error): *"Import appcompat 23.0.1 instead of the latest version will solve this problem."*

Answer (score -1):

Did you have google youtube app on your device?

update youtube app from playstore to the latest, 
or you can install it if you dont have.
then run the youtube app,

last step, try run your own app with youtube player again.
tell me if it works.